# MSI Install Features in a Sequence

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Is there a way to install features in a sequence, i.e `Feature_NonSMIFiles` and `Feature_SMIFiles` should install after the installation of `DefaultFeature` ?

I see in log that DefaultFeature is being installed at last.

```
MSI (s) (F4:20) [16:19:10:784]: Feature: Feature_NonSMIFiles; Installed: Absent;   Request: Local;   Action: Local
MSI (s) (F4:20) [16:19:10:784]: Feature: Feature_SMIFiles; Installed: Absent;   Request: Null;   Action: Null
MSI (s) (F4:20) [16:19:10:784]: Feature: DefaultFeature; Installed: Absent;   Request: Local;   Action: Local
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Why is the order so important?

Comment: I suppose you could split the MSI in several setups and run them in the desired sequence - if this installation order is really needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSI doesn't install feature-by-feature. Actions that write to the machine (e.g., `InstallFiles` to copy files to the machine) take into account all components in all features that are selected for installation.